# Integrate data from sql database to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint

We want to integrate data from a sql database to sharepoint online, I saw that there are solutions like layer2 but it is not free. is there any other alternative to do it thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options for you to connect sql database:

1.Azure SQL:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28286.office-365-sharepoint-online-bcs-with-azure-sql-server-database.aspx

2.Use Azure Hybrid Connections:
https://asishpadhy.com/2018/01/19/getting-on-premises-data-from-sql-to-sharepoint-online-using-azure-hybrid-connections/

3.Custom WCF Service

Reference:
https://www.peters.com/blog/exposing-sql-data-sharepoint-online/